# React setState of array of objects syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the function below that is used to dynamically update a list of objects when the textarea is typed into:

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
//array of these objects
//0: {
//Category: "Some_ID"
//Description: "Some Description"
//Question: "Some Question.."
//}

function EditQuestion(e) {
    const updatedQuestions = questions;
    updatedQuestions[e.target.dataset.index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setQuestions([...updatedQuestions]);
  }

//somewhere in the return..
<textarea
  className="textarea"
  value="Description"
  data-index="1"
  name="Description"
  onChange={EditQuestion}
  />
```

My question is what is the **spread operator** doing here that makes this work:

`setQuestions([...updatedQuestions]);`

and the reason these don't work, or give unwanted results when setting the state?

`setQuestions([updatedQuestions]);` or
`setQuestions(updatedQuestions);` ?

Answer (score 0):

The first case:

```
setQuestions([updatedQuestions]);
```

This case will not work because you have to pass an array of items, not an array of array.

The second case:

```
setQuestions(updatedQuestions);
```

This case will not work, because of this line :

```
const updatedQuestions = questions;
```

You need to use immutable data because you just passed the same **value(reference)**, and **React** will think that its the same value and will not rerender the component, it can work if you updated your code like this :

```
const updatedQuestions = {...questions}; //this line will create new array instead of pointing to old one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well imagine that `updateQuestions` is just a `[{}, {}]` (array of objects) and when you just put `setQuestions([updatedQuestions])` you pretty much doing this `setQuestions([ [{}, {}] ])` (Array of array of objects)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This doesn't exactly answer your question about the spread operator, but it does something that I think is more important for you.

This pattern is everywhere and it's so wrong:

```
function EditQuestion(e) {
    const updatedQuestions = questions; <- this line is irrelevant, confusing, and a huge bug trap
    ...
  }
```

It's irrelevant because you now have two variables - `updatedQuestions` and `questions` which both access the exact same object in memory, but a lot of people seem to think that they're different. See half the answers on SO about "my component didn't rerender after I updated my state"

To answer a part of your question, this won't work:

```js
function EditQuestion(e) {
    const updatedQuestions = questions;
    updatedQuestions[e.target.dataset.index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setQuestions(updatedQuestions); 
  }
```

Because, as I just pointed out, `questions === updatedQuestions` - you mutated state. Rule #1 in react - don't mutate state.

A better `EditQuestion` implementation looks like this:

```
function EditQuestion(e) {
    setQuestions((questions) => {
      // questions is now a variable containing your existing questions state
       
      // map returns a "NEW" array - therefore this isn't mutating state
      return questions.map((q,i) => {
        // this is not the question we're interested in, so just return q
        if(i != e.target.dataset.index) return q;
   
        // this is the question we're interested in, update it
        // be sure to return a new object and not mutate the old one
        return {...q, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `questions` variable is an array that should only be modified by using the `setQuestions` function. The parameter you give to `setQuestions` should be the new array. Let's explore why the following don't work:

```js
setQuestions([updatedQuestions])
```

Here you're passing an array of an array. That's not what `questions` is supposed to be.  It will not crash, but you end up with a nested array which isn't what you expected.

```js
setQuestions(updatedQuestions);
```

This won't work because the object you're sending is really the original `questions` object since both variables (questions and updatedQuestions) just point to the same array. Since it's not changing the `setQuestions` won't really change the value.

I think  you intended to build a copy of the questions and add to it, so this code would make more sense:

```js
function EditQuestion(e) {
    const updatedQuestions = [...questions];  // copies to a new array
    updatedQuestions[e.target.dataset.index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setQuestions(updatedQuestions);  // replace the original with the new array
}
```

Regarding the spread operator, you can use that to get a shallow copy of the array. For example:

```js
const x = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];
const y = [ ...x ];
// changing y doesn't change x
y.push({ c: 3 });
console.log('x:', x);
console.log('y:', y);

// but both point to the same objects within
y[1].b = 22;
console.log(`x[1].b ${x[1].b} y[1].b: ${y[1].b}`)
// you might expect x[1].b to still be 2 but it's not
```

So in your example, the spread operator helps you build a shallow copy of the `questions` array which means `setQuestions` sees a new array coming in and replaces the old with the new.

Comment: This is still less than ideal because you are still performing a mutation on a questions object. If a component lower in the tree relies on it getting a new reference, you'll be stuck with a really confusing bug.

Comment: that's true, if the objects within the array need to be immutable but that's not what the question here is about. If the objects within the array are simply used when the state changes then there's no problem here. I didn't want to complicate the answer going past the scope of the original question

Comment: The safest way to deal with data in react is to treat everything as immutable. Full stop. If you start cherry-picking it's ok to mutate this, but it's not okay to mutate that, then you're going to end up with problems eventually and they'll be very confusing ones at that.

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS re-renders whenever there is a change in state or props. In your case to see if the state has changed it does shallow caparison of previous & new state props. Here you have a non-primitive data structure where state questions are actually storing the reference to the value stored in memory.

```js
const questions = [{ questionName: 'old question' }];
const updatedQuestions = questions;
updatedQuestions[0].questionName = "edited question"; // mutating the nested value;
questions === updatedQuestions; // this will print true, since they still refer to the same reference

const destructuredQuestions = [...updatedQuestions] // also this only works for 1st layer, deep nested are still connected
questions === destructuredQuestions // this will print false, on restructuring it start storing the reference to new memory
```

From experience, I highly recommend restructuring nested things before mutating/update the values.

Comment: You're still mutating something. It might be inconsequential depending how your lower components are structured, but it also might not be and you'll have a heck of a time figuring out why. Advice: don't mutate anything in react, always use a new reference.